# Detect any tap outside the current view

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Is there a way to detect any tap outside the current view? I unsuccessfully tried to implement something with the hitTest method but I am not sure to understand it well.

Comment: have you tried  touchesBegan: method

Comment: You may want to add a tapGesture on the view containing the current view.

Comment: I'm doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48790850/7132300

Answer (score 24):

What you have to do is, In **touchesBegan** you have to get the first touch object from the **touches** set and you have to check the location of that touch in a view(inside which you want to detect the touch).

After you get the location of touch in View, you have to check whether your **currentView**(The view which you have to check whether tap was inside or outside).

If currentView's frame contains the touch location, that means touch has occurred inside the view otherwise outside.

```swift
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    let touch = touches.first
    guard let location = touch?.location(in: self.view) else { return }
    if !currentView.frame.contains(location) {
        print("Tapped outside the view")
    } else {
        print("Tapped inside the view")
    }
}
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Don't you have to call `super` too?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei the above code, with and without `super`

Comment: Yes, but, it works ok regardless for a quick test. I was thinking that maybe there are some cases in which not calling `super` would cause issues, because [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan?language=objc) states this also: **When creating your own subclasses, call super to forward any events that you do not handle yourself.**

Answer (score 15):

You can use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol

```
    extension YourViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

      func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
                             shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        return (touch.view === self.view)
      } 
    }
```

This will only returns "true" when the touch was on the background view but "false" if it was inside the your View.

Note : The identity operator === to compare touch.view with self.view. You want to know whether both variables refer to the same object.

And in viewDidLoad() you will create the gestureRecognizer and set delegate.

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: #selector(yourActionMethod))
gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

Comment: This is what I need, very short and works perfectly for me! Thank you.